# Signature of method __int__ does not match signature of base method in class This inspection detects inconsistencies in overriding method signatures

Tags: python-3.x, multiple-inheritance

I am new to Python and currently facing issue with multiple inheritance.
Below is my code that i have written, for which i am getting following error

Signature of method 'Product.**int**()' does not match signature of base method in class 'RawMaterial'
Inspection info: This inspection detects inconsistencies in overriding method signatures.

Code Snippet:

```
class RawMaterial:
    def __int__(self,rmname,rmstate):
        print("Raw material class instantiated")
        self.rmname = rmname
        self.rmstate = rmstate

    def raw_material_details(self):
        print("Raw Material Name : ", self.rmname)
        print("Raw Material State : ", self.rmstate)

class Worker:
    def __int__(self,workid,wname,processid):
        print("Worker class instantiated")
        self.workid = workid
        self.wname = wname
        self.processid = processid

    def worker_details(self):
        print("Work ID : ", self.workid)
        print("Worker Name: ", self.wname)
        print("Process ID : ", self.processid)

class Product(RawMaterial, Worker):
    def __int__(self, pname, pbatch, rmname, rmstate, workid, wname, processid):
        print("Product class instantiated")
        RawMaterial.__init__(rmname, rmstate)
        Worker.__init__(workid, wname, processid)
        self.pname = pname
        self.pbatch = pbatch

    def product_details(self):
        print("Product Name : ",self.pname)
        print("Product Batch : ",self.pbatch)


prod1 = Product("Pepsi","ZA443","Water","Liquid",12,"Alpha",443)
prod1.product_details()
```

Comment: Surely you mean `__init__`?

Comment: Just to emphasize: the typo in spelling __init__ as __int__ is the cause of this issue.